# Why haven't you been on?

Tags: grammar

> Why haven't you been on social media since Sometime ?

Or

> Why haven't you been on social media since a while?

These are grammatically correct. Which one is the most suitable? Or else please give some suggestions.

Comment: Please add more detail to explain why you think both sentences are correct (they aren't) and which one you think might be suitable, and why?  Any information you can add will be helpful, otherwise the question should be closed as "proofreading".

Answer (score 2):

The closest phrase you could use I think is

> "Why haven't you been on social media in a while".

"A while" is a period of time, so you would use the preposition "in" - you stopped doing the thing at some unspecified point *in* this range.

"Since" implies a specific event - *i.e.* "since your birthday", so you can't use "since  sometime". Note as well that "sometime" should be two words --> "some time" (*i.e.* How much time? Some.)

Answer (score 1):

Both of those sentences are incorrect.

Try these:

Why haven't you been on social media?

Why haven't you been on social media since your graduation?

You haven't been on social media for quite some time. Why?